# python dataframe iterate and plot/graph

Tags: python, dataframe

Newbie question, I have a dataframe created from csv with approx 100K rows

```
    LINE    Line ID     HOURS   CONVERSION  Interval
0   BUR     0           42      75.00       48
1   SHK     1           15      100.00      24
2   BHH     14          16      65.16       24
3   GAT     2           71      50.00       72
4   MKT     23          60      100.00      60
```

I want to be able to iterate over each row and graph Interval on x axis and CONVERSION on y
for each LINE/Line ID, whats the best way to do this?

Comment: you want to see them animated?

Comment: What have you tried so far based on your own research, and what was wrong with your attempt(s)? Please provide a [mcve] so that we better understand how to help you

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use `plot()` method of dataframe if you just want to plot:

```
df.plot(x= 'Interval', y = 'CONVERSION')
```

results in:

[image]

If you want a separate line for each line, you can iterate over but you can opt-in for plotly which would be better and easier. And you get an interactive, more beautiful graph:

```
pd.options.plotting.backend = 'plotly'
df.plot(x= 'Interval', y = 'CONVERSION', color = 'Line')
```

[image]

P.S.

- You do not need to iterate in pandas unless absolutely necessary. Operations are vectorized in their very nature.
- I used extended version of your dataframe to demonstrate lines in plotly graph with last column mutated:

  ```
       LINE    Line ID     HOURS   CONVERSION  Interval
   0   BUR     0           42      75.00       48
   1   SHK     1           15      100.00      24
   2   BHH     14          16      65.16       24
   3   GAT     2           71      50.00       72
   4   MKT     23          60      100.00      60
   0   BUR     0           42      75.00       49
   1   SHK     1           15      100.00      28
   2   BHH     14          16      65.16       30
   3   GAT     2           71      50.00       78
   4   MKT     23          60      100.00      61
  ```

Comment: appreciate the help @Hamza what do you mean used 'extended version of dataframe' and 'mutated' last column?

Comment: I added new values to your dataframe with values in last column changed so we have different data in last column so that we can use it to plot. See the dataframe I added in the answer for more intuition

Comment: I see, I think I asked about iterate because I dont want to show all the lines on a single graph (which is just too much data to be usable for user) I would rather show maybe 20-25 line per graph then show the next 25 and so on.